# No service names in UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I'm trying to use UIActivityViewController to share an image from my app. This is the source code:

```
UIImage *sourceImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[self currentMedia] path]];
NSArray *activityItems = @[sourceImage];
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
avc.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
[avc release];
[sourceImage release];
```

Everything works fine except for one issue: I don't see service names  (Email, Twitter, Facebook etc) in the service picker. Look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ARC and don't have such problem. As far as UIActivityViewController is hardly rely on multithreading and blocks it is possible to affect some objects lifetime. So I would try to switch to ARC as recommends Apple or at least to make retained class property for `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: thank you! looks like ARC is the issue. since I can't convert my project to ARC right now I have to postpone introducing UIActivityViewController in my app for some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `nil` for the activity types *and* you specify excluded types, nothing will show up.

However if you just pass `nil` for the first parameter, all the available built-in service types will show up.

I'm still having a bit of trouble getting this API to behave as I want it to, but that's one thing I did find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIActivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for this purpose. Activity objects are used in conjunction with a `UIActivityViewController` object, which is responsible for presenting services to the user.

look into `activityTitle` method of `UIActivity` class it returns string that describes the service.

Here is [Example project](https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-uiactivity).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't want to create my own UIActivity subclasses for system services like e-mail, Twitter or Facebook - they are working as expected. I just want service names to be shown below their respective icons.